# How to make the URL valid in java?

Tags: java, spring

When i tried to validate below URL using UrlValidator in java,it fails

```
file:/home/work/jaison/pod/build/tmp/jettyRunWar/webapp/WEB-INF/pods/tempPreview/1045/160/index.html
```

how to pass validateUrl check for this url in java?
thanks in advance

Comment: `file://home...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is for a UNIX / Linux / MacOS X file, the syntax is

```
file://home/work/jaison/...
```

or

```
file:///home/work/jaison/...
```

For Windows, it must be:

```
file:///home/work/jaison/...
```

or

```
file:///c:/home/work/jaison/...
```

On Windows, the form with two slashes is a network share pathname; i.e. "home" in "file:///home/work/jaison" would be misinterpreted as a host name.

Reference:

- ["file URI scheme"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) - Wikipedia